# Qt After drop event

Tags: qt, events, pyqt, drag-and-drop, qlistwidget

I need to process some data AFTER a drop event has occured on a widget.

i.e a user selects some items in list A and drops them in list B. My program needs to compare the 2 lists after B has added the items selected from A.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PyQt script that demonstrates two ways to trap drop events:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.listA = ListWidget(self)
        self.listB = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.listB.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        for widget in (self.listA, self.listB):
            widget.setAcceptDrops(True)
            widget.setDragEnabled(True)
            for item in 'One Two Three Four Five Six'.split():
                widget.addItem(item)
            layout.addWidget(widget)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Drop and
            source is self.listB.viewport()):
            self.listB.dropEvent(event)
            if event.isAccepted():
                print 'eventFilter', self.listB.count()
            return True
        return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)

class ListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QListWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QListWidget.dropEvent(self, event)
        if event.isAccepted():
            print 'dropEvent', self.count()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: tableView-> **viewport()** ->installEventFilter(this) is the important part here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The event you're listening for is [`QDropEvent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdropevent.html). To do some work on receipt of the event you'll need to either:

- Reimplement [`QWidget::dropEvent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#dropEvent) on the target widget **or**
- Use a separate controller widget as an event filter for the drop target (reimplement [`QObject::eventFilter`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#eventFilter) on the controller and then install it on the target [[`installEventFilter`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#installEventFilter)]).

---

**EDIT**: Going into more depth:

1. **Reimplementing** `dropEvent`

*Header:*

```
cDropTarget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  cDropTarget(QWidget *Parent = 0);

protected:
  virtual void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
}
```

*Implementation:*

```
cDropTarget::cDropTarget(QWidget *Parent)
  : QWidget(Parent)
{
  setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void cDropTarget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
  //check that you want to process the drop event
  //i.e. its mimeData()->hasFormat(that you can interpret)

  //extract mimeData() from the drop event

  //do something with it
}
```

1. **Using a separate event filter**

*header:*

```
cDropEventFilter : public QObject
{
   ...

protected:
  virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);

   ...
}
```

*Implementation:*

```
bool cDropEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
  if(event->type() == QEvent::DropEnter)
  {
    QDropEvent *DropEvent = static_cast<QDropEvent*>(event);
    if (DropEvent->mimeData()->hasFormat(MIME_TYPE))
    {

      DropEvent->acceptProposedAction();
      return true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
  }

  //Handle all events not matching mimeData format MIME_TYPE
  event->ignore();
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you pls give an example?

Comment: I tried creating my own list class before and overriding the drop event with my own custom one but couldn't get the code to keep the dropped widgets. Thanks for the detail and examples though :)

Answer (score 1):

### Got it working!

#### My code for anyone interested:

```
class MyList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyList, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.setDragDropMode( QAbstractItemView.InternalMove ) 


    def dropEvent( self , event ):
        # get index to insert at
        insertPos   = event.pos()
        fromList    = event.source()
        insertRow   = fromList.row( fromList.itemAt( insertPos ) )
    
        lowestRow = insertRow
        for item in fromList.selectedItems():
            name = item.text()
            sip.delete( item )
        
            listItem = QListWidgetItem( name )
            listItem.setTextAlignment( Qt.AlignHCenter )
            self.insertItem( insertRow , listItem ) 
            insertRow += 1
        
        self.emit( SIGNAL("stuffDropped") , lowestRow )
    
        event.accept()
```